# Почему в одном проекте пропала информация о всех классах, а в другом она есть?

Tags: visual-studio

Пропала возможность развернуть какой-либо файлик и посмотреть его список методов/полей/свойств, куда могло деться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Namespace классов соответствует проекту?

Comment: Да, соответствуют